# Concatenate every element of list with a list without loops

Tags: python

Is there a way to concatenate every element of a list with a different list without a loop?
Let's do an example:
I have the list [5,10,15] and want to get a list with [0,0] between each element. So the result would be [5,0,0,10,0,0,15,0,0]

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: At a low level, no. You could use numpy to skip having to write the loops.

Comment: How could you use numpy for that?

Comment: "Well yes but actually no"

Comment: For example I have the array [5,3,4] and want to get an array with [0000] between each element

Comment: @Pilki one way is [`np.concat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: That still makes no sense. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65797788/edit) your question and post example input and output

Comment: @Pilki That looks like *interleaving* two lists, rather than concatenating them. Please edit your question and add an example that shows the two input lists and what you expect as output.

Comment: Why without loop? And what exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: @Pilki One-liner: `[x for a in list1 for x in (a, *list2)]`. If this is unacceptable because it uses loops, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

"Without loop" is unclear, but here's something without a `for` statement, `while` statement, comprehension or generator expression:

```
>>> a = [5, 10, 15]
>>> b = [0, 1]
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> [*chain(*zip(a, *map(repeat, b)))]
[5, 0, 1, 10, 0, 1, 15, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

A Small Recursive Function to Concat items with a custom delimiter(separator).

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]

def getNext(list, delimeter=""):
    if(len(list) == 0):
        return ""
    else:
        elem = list.pop()
        return getNext(list, delimeter) + delimeter + elem

print(getNext(a.copy(), " "))
```

**Output :**

```
1 2 3
```